# Can you color individual items in a data validation drop-down list in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

It's as simple as this. Say I want to color "COPT" and "RAT GCU" Yellow can I color just those?

I tried conditional formatting tricks and they all work after the drop down item is selected.

I want the colors to be loaded only to certain list items to appear as soon as I click the drop-down arrow.

I'm not sure if this can be done but...

Additionally would anyone know the syntax to click a button to set the value of the list back to displaying "Please select"???? I already have a reset button that unfilters everything. So if I tie it to that button I think it'd work like a charm. I just don't know how to go about selecting the listbox as it's a data validation one and I can't seem to figure out how to define/declare the listbox and can't find it's name anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to color items in the DV list. If you want the cell to show "Please Select" when no choice was made, all you can do is enter that literal text into the cell. An empty cell will remain empty.

Comment: Alright, I didn't think so but thought I'd ask. Thank you for your response.